# How to create a simple PHP array from a result in a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I have a MySQL database that has a column with a bunch of descriptions. I want those in a PHP array imitating this:

```
$Description[0] = "Here's a description";
$Description[1] = "Here's another description";
$Description[2] = "Wow, many descriptions";
$Description[3] = "Another one";
$Description[4] = "They just keep going";
...etc
```

I'm struggling with the while loop logic to make this happen though. Help!

Comment: and what have you tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create this array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747356/how-do-i-create-this-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
$Description = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($Description, $row["columnyouwant"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Description = array();
$result = mysql_query(......);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $Description[] = $row;
}
// echo print_r($Description);
```

Answer (score -1):

hi very simple...

```
foreach ($Description as $value) {
   echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should've specified. I just want to pull the information from my MySQL database and store the values into the $Description array, not echo them out. I don't have the values in the array yet, that's what I need help with. A While loop to pull those from my database and plop them in there.